# python поиск файла и его полного пути на диске

Tags: python, ос

Нужно по имеющемуся имени файла (с расширением) найти его на диске, а потом выдать его расположение.
Попыталась сделать так..
Не то выдает.

```
def passage(findThis, beginSearchThere):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(beginSearchThere):
        for filename in filenames:
            print(filename)
            if (filename == findThis):
                find = True
                filesPath = '\''+ dirpath + '\''
                return filesPath
    return None
```

Делала filename.abspath и тоже не работало:

```
for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk('/home/elina/elya'):
    for filename in filenames:
        print(os.path.abspath(filename))
```

Comment: Что именно "не то выдает"?

Comment: Внутри цикла вам надо объединять имена файлов с путём и с точкой поиска, чтобы получить полный путь к найденному файлу. Посмотрите готовые примеры или ещё лучше документацию на сайте python.org.

Comment: следуйте pep-8 в выборе имён, если нет специальных потребностей. Вместо `passage(findThis`, beginSearchThere)` можно использовать `find(filename, rootdir)` (lowercase вместо camelCase)

Answer (score 2):

в python 3.6 появилась удобрая функция [os.scandir](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0471/) которая возвращает [path-like](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-path-like-object) object

```
import os

def passage(file_name, folder):
    for element in os.scandir(folder):
        if element.is_file():
            if element.name == file_name:
                yield folder
        else:
            yield from passage(file_name, element.path)

print(*passage('system.py', os.getcwd()))  # C:\Scripts\new1\libs
```

Answer (score 2):

Чтобы в заданном дереве директорий вывести путь к первому файлу с указанным именем:

```
from pathlib import Path

print(next(Path(beginSearchThere).rglob(findThis)))
```

Если `beginSearchThere` это полный путь, то этот код напечатает полный путь к файлу. В противном случае, чтобы получить абсолютный путь (без символьных ссылок, с убранными `..`, итд), [можно `Path.resolve()` метод вызвать](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pathlib.Path.html#pathlib.Path.resolve).