# Нахождение полного имени по имени папки

Tags: python, python-3.x, файловая-система

У меня, например, есть имя папки - papka3
Могу ли я получить её полный путь? Что-то вроде: 'C:\papka1\papka2\papka3'?

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [python поиск файла и его полного пути на диске](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/690011/python-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%b0-%d0%b8-%d0%b5%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%bf%d1%83%d1%82%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если ты работаешь с файлом или папкой в текущем каталоге - то да

Для файла

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("mydir/myfile.txt")
'C:/example/cwd/mydir/myfile.txt'
```

Для папки

```
>>> import os
>>> os.path.abspath("papka3 ")
'C:\\papka1\\papka2\\papka3'
```